# regex split a string between [ and ]

Tags: php, regex

My string is something like that '[15][18][22]' and now I like so split it into an array of [15] and [18] and [22]. I'm trying with this regex

```
\[\d+\]
```

But it only split the first one.

thanks for help

Comment: why don't you just do :

`var array = string.substr(1,string.length-1).split("][")` it could fit your needs for this very case

(substr() removes the first [ and last [)

Comment: thanks but I need the [] as well. This is for an sql select with '%[15]% OR  %[18]% OR %[22]%

Comment: @StillerEugen: Are you doing this split in Javascript?

Comment: @anubhava, no I'm doing it in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using `preg_match_all` with what you want to capture:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\[\d+]/', $str, $m)) {
   print_r($m[0]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [15]
    [1] => [18]
    [2] => [22]
)
```

Or else you may use this `preg_split` with a capture group:

```
$str = '[15][18][22]';
$arr = preg_split('/(\[\d+])/', $str, -1,
                  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [15]
    [1] => [18]
    [2] => [22]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't get any simpler than this.  Three characters in the pattern.  You only need to explode on the zero-width position after each `]`.  `\K` tells the regex engine to forget/release the previously matched character.

`~]\K~` [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rumova/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/n3qJg))

```
$string = '[15][18][22]';
var_export(preg_split('~]\K~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '[15]',
  1 => '[18]',
  2 => '[22]',
)
```

This will perform with maximum efficiency because it doesn't have any capture groups, lookarounds, or alternatives to slow it down.